# Serialized field fails to save rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I added a serialized column to my database...

```
class AddRegQuestionsColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
   add_column :users, :reg_questions, :text
  end
end  

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :reg_questions
     serialize :reg_questions, hash
end
```

Ran rake db:migrate

Then tried to pass a hash to the field in rails console...

```
[1] pry(main)> a=User.new
 => #<User:0x3ffa10aef3e0>

[2] pry(main)> a.reg_questions={"9"=>"Yes", "10"=>"Yes", "11"=>"Yes", "12"=>"Yes", "13"=>"Yes", "14"=>"Yes", "15"=>"Yes", "16"=>"Yes"}
=> {"9"=>"Yes",
   "10"=>"Yes",
   "11"=>"Yes",
   "12"=>"Yes",
   "13"=>"Yes",
   "14"=>"Yes",
   "15"=>"Yes",
   "16"=>"Yes"}

[3] pry(main)> a.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After you call `a.save`, what does `a.errors` return?

Comment: Thanks! a.errors solved the issue, I had validations that needed to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Well for sure you need to serialize `Hash`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was that I had not full-filled the validations necessary to save.  It had nothing to do with the serialized field I added.

```
a.save provided...

@messages=
{ :email=>["can't be blank", 
           "can't be blank"],
 :password=>["can't be blank"]}
```

Rossta provided a good way to trouble shoot save errors by using .errors.

Dana, I tested with and without hash, it seemed to work in both cases.  Thank you for your feedback.

Thank you everyone.